# add admin after index.php it will redirect to default url

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am using php codeigniter. when i enter **admin** after index.php it should redirect to default controller with admin  like userlogin/admin.

```
 $route['admin'] = 'http://localhost/index.php/user_login/admin';
```

when i enter **user** after index.php it should redirect to default controller with user like userlogin/user.

```
$route['admin'] = 'http://localhost/index.php/user_login/user';
```

now when i type user_login/admin or user_login/user it will redirect to admin or user.how can i achieve this?

Comment: must be having some login based on roles, based on successful login check role of user and redirect to that url.

Comment: is your 2nd route meant to be $route['user'] and not $route['admin']

Comment: yes my routes like $route['admin'] = 'user_login/admin';
$route['user'] = 'user_login/user';

Comment: i am asking when i am having index.php if i type admin it should redirect to user_login/admin

Comment: i have done based on successful login check role of user and redirect to that ur

Comment: So have you created your methods for user and admin in your user_login controller? Can you access them both with the full url instead of the $route... Are you asking on how to perform a redirect('controller_name'); ? I am a little confused as to what you are asking.

Comment: yes i have created user_login controller for both user and admin.i can access with full url.i can login in both user and admin that is not a problem

Comment: when i type 'http://localhost/index.php/admin', my URL should  look like below 'http://localhost/index.php/user_login/admin';